# How to print the compiled instructions in V8 engine?

Tags: v8, chromium

I have compiled the v8_hello_world sample and it could print "hello world" in the console. I know that V8 compiles the JavaScript with JIT, but I want to print the detailed message such as instructions it compiled. And I also want to know the types of these instructions, so what should I do?

Thank you very much~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the type(s) of generated code you're interested in, you'll have to pass the corresponding flag(s) to V8:

- `--print-code` prints unoptimized machine code (created by "full codegen", the unoptimizing compiler)
- `--print-bytecode` prints bytecode (created by the "Ignition" interpreter)
- `--print-opt-code` prints optimized machine code (created by either the "Crankshaft" or "TurboFan" optimizing compilers)

These flags (and many others) are documented by `--help`. Since major changes to the execution pipeline are currently ongoing, depending on which version of V8 you're using, you might see the same function compiled by different compilers.

If you use the developer shell `d8`, you can pass these flags directly on the command-line. In your own embedding application, you can use `v8::V8::SetFlagsFromCommandLine` to pass `argc` and `argv` to V8. In `d8.cc` you can see an example for how to handle some flags yourself and pass on others to V8.

---

Update one year later: "full codegen" and "Crankshaft" are gone. `--print-bytecode` still prints bytecode, `--print-opt-code` prints optimized machine code (now always from "Turbofan"). `--print-code` has less to do than before, but is still useful for generated regexp code and wasm code.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It helps me a lot!

Comment: @jmrk I got little confused.  what is Hydrogen and Lithium ?

I read about them article http://www.mattzeunert.com/2015/08/19/viewing-assembly-code-generated-by-v8.html

Comment: @DineshRavi: Those were the internal names of the high-level and low-level intermediate representations of the "Crankshaft" optimizing compiler. It has since been replaced by "Turbofan".